# Overflow when using projwin with gdal_translate

Tags: gdal

Given the following dataset:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: eudem_dem_3035_europe.tif
Size is 240000, 200000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["ETRS89 / LAEA Europe",
    GEOGCS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",52],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",10],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",4321000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",3210000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3035"]]
Origin = (2000000.000000000000000,6000000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (25.000000000000000,-25.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 2000000.000, 6000000.000) ( 51d50'39.04"W, 66d46'12.03"N)
Lower Left  ( 2000000.000, 1000000.000) ( 13d41' 3.88"W, 28d46'45.49"N)
Upper Right ( 8000000.000, 6000000.000) ( 86d 0'31.83"E, 56d26'45.47"N)
Lower Right ( 8000000.000, 1000000.000) ( 46d30'12.69"E, 24d 4'54.00"N)
Center      ( 5000000.000, 3500000.000) ( 20d26' 6.96"E, 54d 9'53.47"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=-226.887 Max=5111.089
  Minimum=-226.887, Maximum=5111.089, Mean=341.729, StdDev=493.987
  NoData Value=nan
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=5111.0888671875
    STATISTICS_MEAN=341.72920322335
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-226.8865814209
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=493.98749395974
```

when using gdal_translate to extract something from lower right corner:

```
-projwin 7999000 1002025 8000000 1002000
```

an error is thrown

```
Input file size is 240000, 200000
0ERROR 1: TIFFFillTile:Read error at row 4294967295, col 4294967295; got 0 bytes, expected 1534
ERROR 1: TIFFReadEncodedTile() failed.

ERROR 1: eudem_dem_3035_europe.tif, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 937, Y offset 780
ERROR 1: GetBlockRef failed at X block offset 937, Y block offset 780
```

It works if extracting something where y>4915900.000, and seeing that it tried to read from `4294967295` which is `2^32 = (4294967295+1)`

Anyone with suggestions to what can be done? I am using geodata/gdal for running the commands on docker.

with debug on

```
GDAL: GDALOpen(eudem_dem_3035_europe.tif, this=0x1364b20) succeeds as GTiff.
Input file size is 240000, 200000
0GDAL: GDALDefaultOverviews::OverviewScan()
GDAL: GDAL_CACHEMAX = 348 MB
GDAL: GDALDatasetCopyWholeRaster(): 330*256 swaths, bInterleave=0
ERROR 1: TIFFFillTile:Read error at row 4294967295, col 4294967295; got 0 bytes, expected 159448
ERROR 1: TIFFReadEncodedTile() failed.

ERROR 1: eudem_dem_3035_europe.tif, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 237, Y offset 417
GDAL: GDALClose(eudem_dem_3035_europe.tif, this=0x1364b20)
```

Comment: Re-run with `--debug on`. Perhaps you'll get more information.

Comment: updated with info

Comment: Just discovered that the file was only partly downloaded and missing data - this could be the issue. No idea why the error came out as this though, but trying to download the file again.

Comment: Everything works as expected when the file is all good :) doh

Answer (score 2):

Turned out that the file that we was clipping from was not fully downloaded and that caused the error.